# What could fix Calendar.app when one calendar does not show all events that should be synced with iCloud?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, icloud, ical, calendar

I use iCloud to sync 4 calendars between my iPhone 4 (running iOS 6.0.1), iPad 2 (running iOS 6.0.1) and MacBook Pro Mid 2012 running Mountain Lion (10.8.2).

All events for 3 of the calendars sync correctly across all devices, however for one calendar:

- All events show at https://www.icloud.com
- All events show in the calendar app on the iPhone and iPad
- Hardly any events appear in Calendar.app on the MacBook Pro, some future events appear until after the date of the event and disappear from this calendar while remaining on the iOS devices and iCloud.com.

I noticed it happening in the last few weeks. Previously it worked OK. I usually add events to the calendar from either my iPhone or MacBook.

So far I have tried:

1. Removing the calendar from my MacBook Pro (signing out of iCloud, then deleting all calendars from `~/Library/Calendars`)
2. Restarting OS X
3. Re-adding the calendar

– but there are still events missing.

In Console I see no messages when I force refresh the calendar.

My Apple ID is a custom email, not the typical @me.com address (not sure that should make a difference).

Does anyone have any other suggestions for what could be causing it or how to fix Calendar syncing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved itself. I'm assuming that iCloud has been updated and that's fixed it as nothing I tried made a difference and most of the answers here weren't even relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings* > *Mail, Contacts, Calendars* and then Sync and all events that should get all your events to show.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! Thank you for your answer — it looks a bit incomplete, could you please check so that it makes more sense? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I've been away! The problem is with Mountain Lion, not iOS - those instructions are for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I've tried numerous things to no avail. I've just tried to install BusyCal and sync it to iCloud to see what would happen. To my surprise, it cannot show any events from the offending calendar. iCal shows some. BusyCal shows none. I'm starting to think that there is some corruption in the calendar data.

Hope this helps progress a bit. Let me know if you find the answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different! To avoid confusion, answers should really be answers (and not general posts like a message board). You do have some useful info here, though, so feel free to remove this answer and add comments to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

## For iCloud, or for any other calendar service that uses CalDAV

If all events are present and correct on the server:

1. use OS X to [delete the account from Calendar](https://help.apple.com/calendar/mac/10.8/help/index.html?localePath=English.lproj#icl1005)
2. add the account.

The help provided by Apple notes:

> If you delete an iCloud calendar account, the iCloud Calendar service
>   will be turned off in iCloud preferences and Mail, Contacts &
>   Calendars preferences. At any time, you can turn the service back on
>   and your iCloud calendars will reappear in Calendar, up to date. Any
>   devices or other computers using the iCloud Calendar service will
>   continue to have your most recent iCloud calendar information.

If the two steps above do not work for you, then try the equivalent routine on other devices that use the CalDAV service. So:

1. remove the account from all three devices – iPad, iPhone and Mac
2. add the account to the Mac.

If that does not work around the problem, then we should wish for the debug menu but a related question [How do I enable the Debug menu in Calendar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58889/8546) remains unanswered.

A server-specific command, in Terminal, can result in logging of traffic. Results may be comprehensive but time-consuming to interpret.

Probably quicker for troubleshooting: [Like Paulo's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68873/8546), see whether a different CalDAV client – something other than Calendar.app – represents all of what's in iCloud. (This is towards identifying the problem – not discouraging you from eventual reuse of Calendar.app.)

You could try [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/index.html), it's reliable (I use it myself, to work with an older and possibly less compliant CalDAV server). If not BusyCal, maybe Mozilla [Sunbird Beta or the Lightning add-on for Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/).

### Thoughts

A few months ago I had an issue with an event that included an **unusual non-Roman character**, but I can't recall whether the issue was visible in the web interface to iCloud, or in Calendar.

### Console and privacy

If you view all messages, it's normal and proper to **not** see things relating to your *personal* data. This is for privacy. Bear in mind, that Console view of all messages is designed for *all* users of a Mac.

Console may prove useful – to view a different log after running a debug command – but first, try the steps above.

Comment: When I signed out from iCloud on my MacBook, I deleted ALL calendars from ~/Library/Calendars, rebooted and signed back in to iCloud, ALL calendars re-sync however the calendar mentioned still exhibits the same behaviour detailed above.

Comment: Thanks – if my addition of this detail to your question is not correct, please make another edit.

Comment: I've updated it to clarify.

Comment: (… the more recent edition …)

Answer (score 0):

Events you create on your iPhone appear as invitations on the iPad and vice versa. You can only edit events on the device it was created and you can edit events when you are logged in onto Google Calendar.

Comment: I don't use Google Calendar, this question relates to iCloud syncing.